# Best way to make favoruites/related content in tables?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm looking for a good way say, to save favorite images for a specific user in the database. Or if I have a movie, I want to display related movies, you get the idea. I don't know how to do it on a database level (`phpmyadmin`). My idea so far is if I have a table named `Users`, I add a column in it named `Favorites`, in which I enter every ID or Name of the favorite item. The problem is that the content in this column may grow a lot more than I expect, and I don't feel this is a good way to do it. So how do I go about this?

Comment: First of all, don't save numbers comma separated in a column. Read about database normalization. Second, I think your question is a bit too broad...

Comment: you should read about [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a table called "Favourites" with a column called UserID and another column for the ID or name of the favourited items. Then you would have one row for each user/favourite pair.

This allows you to have many favourites per user, and you can maintain arbitrary metadata about each favourited item (for example the time and which it was selected as the favourite).

You can  also answer questions like "Which users have favourited a given item?" with this approach.

This is standard DB modelling for this type of problem.